# Android: Calling javascript from WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

We're coding an app for Android.  It's a `WebView` that contains Html5 pages.  We're using `loadUrl()` webview's method, in order to push some native OS variables to html, such as:

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:myJavascriptFunc('" + myAndroidOSVar + "');");
```

It works pretty fine.  But if we are typing on an input from page while `loadUrl()` is called, we lose focus of our input fields, even if javascript function called just changes a flag on cache.

Do you know other way to call a Javascript function from `WebView` instead of `loadUrl()`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest you can get to avoiding the issue: [WebView hides soft keyboard during loadUrl(), which means a keyboard cannot stay open while calling javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303836/webview-hides-soft-keyboard-during-loadurl-which-means-a-keyboard-cannot-stay)

Basically you are avoiding the `loadUrl` call by queuing up commands on the native side and at an interval letting the JS bridge get the commands and execute using JS `eval()` or something.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how it will respond if you have multiple fields in the webview, but I came up with a workaround to keep the keyboard shown: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776064/513038.  It may be worth trying.

Answer (score -1):

yes, there is a way by adding a `JavaScriptInterface` to your WebView , refer [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/10/call-javascript-inside-webview-from.html) for more explanation and details

Comment: We've already used a javascriptInterfaces, but for this particular case, we need to trigger function from webview side (an android timer on our example).  What we need is other method than webview.loadUrl() that dont mess with UI, cause loadUrl() set focus to webview.