# Alternative way for communication between WebView and native

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using `WebView` and a lot of JavaScript in my native application. If JS side wants to call native functions it's rather smooth using `JavaScriptInterface`. However, if native wants to call JS function it's not so easy. I've tried two solutions so far:

- calling `loadUrl` method with `javascript:something()` URL - not acceptable since when user is typing something on keyboard `WebView` is hiding it after function execution
- asking native side for functions every x seconds (presented by `String` object) and
  call `eval()` on a result - sometimes after setting interval for 1 seconds I was getting those requests after 50-60 seconds!

I am wondering if there's any other way to accomplish this communication model. Let's say create local `Socket`/`HTTP`/something-else server inside app and give access for it to `WebView`. I am looking for any tips how (if it's possible) do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the following code which uses java reflection to call JavaScript from Java. It avoids the following loadUrl bugs:
  1. loadUrl may hide keyboard when your focus in a input.
  2. loadUrl cannot be called too often.

Hopefully this helps:

```
public class AdvancedWebView extends WebView {
    private static final int EXECUTE_JS = 194;
    Method sendMessageMethod;
    Object webViewCore;
    boolean initFailed = false;;
    InputMethodManager imm;


    public AdvancedWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        imm = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        this.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        this.initReflection();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private void initReflection() {
        Object webViewObject = this;
        Class webViewClass = WebView.class;
        try {
            Field f = webViewClass.getDeclaredField("mProvider");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            webViewObject = f.get(this);
            webViewClass = webViewObject.getClass();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // mProvider is only required on newer Android releases.
        }       

        try {
            Field f = webViewClass.getDeclaredField("mWebViewCore");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            webViewCore = f.get(webViewObject);
            if (webViewCore != null) {
                sendMessageMethod = webViewCore.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("sendMessage", Message.class);
                sendMessageMethod.setAccessible(true);      
                System.out.println("sendMessageMethod-----"+sendMessageMethod);
            }
            hasIntercepted = true;
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            hasIntercepted = false;
            //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "PrivateApiBridgeMode failed to find the expected APIs.", e);
        }finally{
            if(sendMessageMethod == null)
            {
                hasIntercepted = false;
            }
        }
    }

    private void loadJs(String url) {
        if (sendMessageMethod == null && !initFailed) {
            initReflection();
        }
        // webViewCore is lazily initialized, and so may not be available right away.
        if (sendMessageMethod != null) {
            //String js = popAndEncodeAsJs();
            Message execJsMessage = Message.obtain(null, EXECUTE_JS, url);
            try {
                sendMessageMethod.invoke(webViewCore, execJsMessage);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                //Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Reflection message bridge failed.", e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: should change    private void loadJs -> public void loadJs; then use webview.loadJs instead of webview.loadUrl when I want to call javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to get an alternate communication model working, but I think I've found a workaround for the loadUrl-hides-the-keyboard issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776064/513038.  Does that help any?