# Autofill logins in Chrome using AccessibilityService Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, accessibilityservice

I am developing an application that requires to auto-fill logins in other installed apps and chrome. I am able to successfully auto-fill logins in other installed apps using AccessibilityService but could not get it working on Chrome browser. I am able to identify the username and password AccessibilityNodeInfo but I am not able to paste the content into it.

This is how I am trying, I am copying the content to be filled into Clipboard and then pasting the content into these username and password fields using AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_PASTE. This technique works well for other installed apps but it fails to paste in Chrome. I am not able to find any relevant posts online except this one - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768010/execute-javascript-in-chrome-from-accessibilityservice), but there is no clear solution in it. Also I am not able to find anything documented on developer site too. Should I be injecting javascript code to paste my content? If so can you please give me an example? I have done that using WebView previously but in this case I don't have reference to the view.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I want to create accessibility service for auto-fill other app's login. Can you provide me some links of examples ?

Answer (score 0):

You can run javascript to accomplish this by executing something like the following:

`document.getElementById("username").val = "username";`

however I doubt if you can just run arbitary js in the chrome app as an outside app.

Answer (score 0):

Well Google doesn't allow that

*"You can't use an AccessibilityService to inject JavaScript"*

*"There are no plans to support javascript extensions or any other method of injecting javascript in Chrome or a WebView."*

You can read more [here...](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/chromium-dev/2VC16XswAaI/7JrklF1sHwoJ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to accomplish the autofill:

```
private void setNodeText(AccessibilityNodeInfo node, String str) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putCharSequence(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_ARGUMENT_SET_TEXT_CHARSEQUENCE, str);
        node.performAction(AccessibilityNodeInfo.ACTION_SET_TEXT, bundle);
}
```