# How the Lasspass android app autofill username/password in chrome?

Tags: android, google-chrome, accessibility, autofill, accessibilityservice

This app can automatically detect user/pass form in website in chrome and autofill them, using accessibility service. https://helpdesk.lastpass.com/lastpass-mobile/lastpass-for-android/

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24768010/execute-javascript-in-chrome-from-accessibilityservice#comment38622977_24863344), they do that by executing javascript on the page. Personally I don't find any injected javascript, nor event listener on those field.

I wonder how this was done? All I can find is how to do this in WebView.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/41895207/1852422