# How to enable site notification in Android WebView?

Tags: android, webview, android-notifications

I'm trying to receive site notification from Android WebView. When i am researching for this topic i encountered things related to onesignal but that's not what i want. Does anyone know about this topic?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about [push notifications for a web app](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications) or something else.

Comment: No, i am talking about message or something else notification for android app. I am trying to receive from web view

Comment: Still unclear what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps useful: [Alternative way for communication between WebView and native](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15067853/295004) You might want to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60130282/edit) your question with what effect you are trying to achieve (sources & destinations) along with what APIs you've looked at.

Comment: There is a website which pushes desktop notifications using chrome. I want to capture those notifications from android webview.